# How to log mySQL queries without indexes?

Tags: mysql, mysqldumpslow

I see there is a nice option how to enable log slow queries and queries without indexes:

```
  SET GLOBAL log_queries_not_using_indexes=1;
  SET GLOBAL log_slow_queries=1;
```

OK, OK, but it seems both write in the same log file I have specified at my.cnf configuration file:

```
  [mysqld]
  long_query_time         = 1
  log-slow-queries        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

I use mysqldumpslow to see the slowest queries, but what I need to do to see separately that queries without indexes?

Comment: I think you will have to do it 1 step at a time.

Comment: BTW, check out mysqlsla as a log analyzer: http://hackmysql.com/mysqlsla

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't. The log file is a text file and you can't infer from it whether a query used an index at that time of execution.
Also, the option `log-queries-not-using-indexes` doesn't necessarily log queries who aren't using an index, [see](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-queries-not-using-indexes):

> If you are using this option with the slow query log enabled, queries
>   that are expected to retrieve all rows are logged. See Section 5.2.5,
>   “The Slow Query Log”. **This option does not necessarily mean that no
>   index is used.** For example, a query that uses a full index scan uses
>   an index but would be logged because the index would not limit the
>   number of rows.